# How to hide / display different page sections with radio input buttons

Tags: html, css, radio-button, label

I'm an amature web developer, just getting my feet wet with my first *proper* html project.

I'm trying to build a webpage where you have a 'tab' selection in the top row and the currently selected tab shows a different section on the main page (hiding the other sections when not selected). I've done this using a radio input inside a label inside a table made of divs, and defined all of what I think is the correct CSS. (see below)

But the tabs do not work: depending on what I change, either every section shows up at once, or none of them do.

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div class="sheet-table">
    <div class="sheet-table-row sheet-candara">
      <div class="sheet-col">
        <label class="container" title="Adventure tab">
          <input type="radio" name="attr_tab" class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab1" value="1">
          <span class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab1 sheet-center">SECTION 1</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="sheet-col">
        <label class="container" title="Lifestyle tab">
          <input type="radio" name="attr_tab" class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab2" value="2">
          <span class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab2 sheet-center">SECTION 2</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="sheet-col">
        <label class="container" title="Options tab">
          <input type="radio" name="attr_tab" class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab3" value="3">
          <span class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab3 sheet-center">SECTION 3</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then later on I have the section content (which I've commented out here):

```
    <div class="sheet-section-tab1">
    <!-- section 1 'adventure' content -->
    </div>
    <div class="sheet-section-tab2">
    <!-- section 2 'lifestyle' content -->
    </div>
    <div class="sheet-section-tab3">
    <!-- section 3 'options' content -->
    </div>
```

And the CSS (a portion of which was copied and edited from [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)):

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sheet-tabs {
  position: inherit;
  padding: 0.2em 0.9em;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.container:hover input ~ .sheet-tabs {
  background-color: rgba(30, 20, 20, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  content: attr(title);
}

.container input:checked ~ .sheet-tabs {
  background-color: rgba(30, 20, 20, 0.7);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

div[class^="sheet-section"] {
    display: none;
}

.sheet-section-tab1,
.sheet-section-tab2,
.sheet-section-tab3 {
  display: none;
}

input.sheet-tab1:checked ~ div.sheet-section-tab1,
input.sheet-tab2:checked ~ div.sheet-section-tab2,
input.sheet-tab3:checked ~ div.sheet-section-tab3{
  display: block;
}
```

Now, the strange thing that I discovered while trying to get this to work was that it *does* work when I take the inputs and spans out of their respective labels and div tables, like so:

```
  <input type="radio" name="attr_tab" class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab1" value="1">
  <span class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab1 sheet-center">SECTION 1</span>
  <input type="radio" name="attr_tab" class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab2" value="2">
  <span class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab2 sheet-center">SECTION 2</span>
  <input type="radio" name="attr_tab" class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab3" value="3">
  <span class="sheet-tabs sheet-tab3 sheet-center">SECTION 3</span>

<div class="sheet-section-tab1">
    <!-- section 1 'adventure' content -->
</div>
<div class="sheet-section-tab2">
    <!-- section 2 'lifestyle' content -->
</div>
<div class="sheet-section-tab3">
    <!-- section 3 'options' content -->
</div>
```

But then I lose all the CSS styling that I worked so hard on...

Is there any way to get the functionality that I desire without compromising on the style, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Or is there just a simple mistake I'm not seeing? Thanks!

(Also, I don't know if this will be relevant to any answers, but for reasons specific to my hosting platform I can't use the `id` attribute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just HTML and CSS to create a tab system like you propose is possible, but is going to be messy and overall inefficient, and styling of the page will be difficult due to how the radio buttons will need to be aligned in order to achieve this. I highly recommend using java script to accomplish what you are doing. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs) is a link to a HowTo on JavaScript tabs. However, if it is a must for this project to be accomplished  through the strict use of HTML and CSS, let me know and I'll take a deeper look. From now what I can tell you is a possible way to accomplish this is to use the "+" selector. Structure the page in a way so that it alternate between radio button and the div/tab to be displayed, as so:

```
radio button
div
radio button
div
radio button
div
```

This way, the radio button is assigned to the div below it. Now you can target a checked radio button through the use of ":checked" and then using "+" which will select the closest div to the radio button. This can be accomplished in css using the following code:

```
.tabs {
display: none;
}

[name="radiobutton"]:checked + .tab {
display: block;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding in your Css overflow:Hidden;